Relative clause question
The mistaken belief, that what he was as doing was not dangerous, was dangerous to his health
In the anovel example is ‘that what he is was doing was not dangerous a relative clause?
It appears to be acting as an adjective modifying “the mistaken belief”, but the relative pronoun of the clause ”that” does not appear to be the object or subject of the relative clause.
In the sentence, “the dog that bit me”, that can be exchanged with the worddog, and dog could become the subject of this clause.
That doesn’t appear to be the case with my example. Is this  different type of relative clause?
`

I think I understand what you're asking, but I think the question is made challenging by several accidental mistakes. Please check for words and letters that shouldn't be there, missing punctuation, etc. Normally I ignore any small mistakes but in this case some of them make me unsure of what you're saying.

I think you’re trying to say

The mistaken belief, that what he was doing was not dangerous, was dangerous to his health.

The clause that what he was doing was not dangerous is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of belief.  It's not a relative clause.
In a relative clause, we can use which, but here we need the complementiser that.
We have a relative clause, though, in the what-phrase

what he was doing

This consists of a noun that and its relative clause which he was doing:
that which he was doing

Interesting point about the choice between What you think is correct and the syntactically correct (but far less common) That which you think is correct. Leading to the syntactically fine (but idiomatically unlikely) The mistaken belief that that which he was doing was not dangerous was dangerous to his health.

Hi, @FumbleFingers, yes.  I like this had had that that article.

Very amusing! I've added the link to WickershamsConscience into my browser favourites for when I fancy some more "meandering digressions". But I'm a bit concerned that (that) WC might turn out to be another "browsing black hole" like TV Tropes. (Where unwary web surfers have been known to die of starvation while feverishly following link after link to the exclusion of all other activities! :)


The mistaken belief ... was bad for his health.

Main clause above.

that
what he was doing
was not dangerous

Declarative content clause with embedded interrogative content clause. It gives supplemental  info about "the mistaken belief".
The sentence could not be rewritten so, transposing the content clause and the NP "the mistaken belief":

That what he was doing was not dangerous, the mistaken belief, was bad for his health. invalid

It would have to be rewritten so:

That what he was doing was not dangerous, a mistaken belief, was bad for his health.

and thus it is not an appositive since the two constituents are not coreferential.
